# Totem 3.10 -no audio mpeg4 aac after 4 seconds-

Tags: sound, totem, mp4

I've a new camcorder Canon and problems with audio when playing on Totem (Ubuntu 14.04). 
The firts 4 seconds sounds perfect, but after then remains silent, with no audio.
The video is perfect, also at 35Mbps when other players fails (Vlc, Mplayer), thats why I need to fix the audio issue.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Run Totem again with system monitor opened (sudo isn't necessary).
Check CPU usage of Totem - If at 99% or 'Over' Typically hardware isn't able to keep up with the demands of the file being accessed.

Codecs are typically CPU-Hogs.

Perhaps try a faster system for best results.